# CKAN docker db init: ERROR: relation "user" does not exist at character 435

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ckan

I'm using latest ckan docker image built from source docker compose with my own .env file

```
docker-compose build
```

After doing a couple of changes in the image to resolve minor bugs (latest ckan needs to install dev-requirements.txt, and entrypoint need to wait for db to be ready), after running `docker-compose up`. I'm getting four similar errors at db container, after which ckan fails to start.

The errors at db container are like this:

`ERROR: relation "user" does not exist at character 435
STATEMENT: SELECT "user".password AS user_password, "user".id AS user_id, "user".name AS user_name, "user".fullname AS user_fullname, "user".email AS user_email, "user".apikey AS user_apikey, "user".created AS user_creat
ed, "user".reset_key AS user_reset_key, "user".about AS user_about, "user".activity_streams_email_notifications AS user_activity_streams_email_notifications, "user".sysadmin AS user_sysadmin, "user".state AS user_state
FROM "user"
WHERE "user".name = 'default' OR "user".id = 'default' ORDER BY "user".name
LIMIT 1`

Pertinent log entries can be found at: http://www.wepaste.com/ckan%20image%20log/

Any hint on what's going on?

Comment: I think this is a sign of an aborted startup. Try removing the volumes for the DB and start it up again (docker volume prune).

Comment: @MattFullerton I deleted everything and start again with 2.7.2 (see my answer below), but what you says makes sense, I'll keep the tip for future problems with the image, thanks.

Comment: For future reference: http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-1.6/paster.html#initialisation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I went to latest "stable" version 2.7.2, and resolve again a couple of bugs to get it working.

The script that modifies the original dockerfile and build a correct image can be found [here](https://github.com/MSO4SC/MSOPortal/blob/master/datacatalogue/create-base-ckan-image.sh).

Comment: The link is broken pal.

Comment: The link is fixed, the file and parent folder were renamed in master branch.